# Python sqlite3 placeholder

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, placeholder

is there a way to set the placeholder for queries in sqlite3 ?
I have some functions that work with a database and it would be more satisfying if they could work both with mysql and sqlite.
Mysql and Postgres python apis use the %s as a placeholder, but sqlite3 use a question mark instead.

I'm looking for a way to use the same placeholder whatever the database engine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my answer with some code to make your SQL "placeholder-agnostic".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated to fix my earlier error about how to use the `paramstyle` global**

If the DB modules you use follow the [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), you can get the module global `paramstyle` which should be any of these:

1. 'qmark'         Question mark style, 
               e.g. '...WHERE name=?'
2. 'numeric'       Numeric, positional style, 
               e.g. '...WHERE name=:1'
3. 'named'         Named style, 
               e.g. '...WHERE name=:name'
4. 'format'        ANSI C printf format codes, 
               e.g. '...WHERE name=%s'
5. 'pyformat'      Python extended format codes, 
               e.g. '...WHERE name=%(name)s'

You can then compose your SQL statements with the placeholder used by the module. You can do something like this:

```
import sqlite3

paramstyle = sqlite3.paramstyle

if paramstyle == 'qmark':
    ph = "?"
elif paramstyle == 'format':
    ph = "%s"
else:
    raise Exception("Unexpected paramstyle: %s" % paramstyle)

sql = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%(ph)s, %(ph)s, %(ph)s)" % { "ph" : ph }
```

Comment: Nothing in the PEP mentions *setting* it. In fact, the PEP describes it as a **constant**.

Comment: Oh you must be right. Being me, I'll try it to see, but you are most probably correct.

Comment: Yup your answer is correct, one must read the value and compose his statement accordingly rather than update the global.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying library [doesn't support `%s`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), so it would need to be replaced manually. It might be easier to check the `paramstyle` attribute and replace all instances of a different placeholder in the query with an appropriate value instead.

Comment: I see. I'm going to make a functions that translates queries with %s to queries with a question mark. However, it's not as easy as it sounds. I cannot find how sqlite escapes the ? itself.